# Can I add more than one link in a content editor web part?

Tags: content-editor-web-part

In this content editor I have referenced a .js file.
If I want to style it with .css file can I connect it also as a link in the same content editor?

For example:

Content Link:

menu.js; menu-style.css

I tried it but with no success.
What is the right way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: You can add links tags in the content editor web parts as mentioned in this reference link: http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Promoted-links-The-New-OTB-Tile-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `<style></style>` tag above `<script>` tag. Define your css inside  tag.

e.g.

```
<style>
.ClassName{display:none;}
</style>
```

OR

You can provide the path of your .css file from .js file as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu-style.css">
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. Is this not going to delay the load process for .css?

Comment: No, Page loads the css first.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative

JSLinks can reference multiple JS and CSS files, on SPOnline also to any https URI

They were created in SP2013 for CSR - Client Side Rendering, but you can use them to load any file.

These files are loaded very early on, so if you execute JS code you have to wait for the DOM to be ready

And that is all JSLink does, it loads files, so the execution is **not** tied to the webpart you attach it to.

You find the JS Link setting in Document/ListView WeParts

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been struggling with the JSLink for hours and it maked things more complex.

Comment: That is called learning.. Blogs about JSLink are deep dives into CSR technology. If you forget CSR and think of JSLinks as the SCRIPT or LINK tags you use to reference external files in an HTML file it makes more sense.. that is all JSLink does: it includes external files

Comment: Learning is always good but the problem is that in Content Editor I can't see any JSLink or the Miscellaneous tab.

Comment: JSLinks are only on Documents/ListView WebParts, if you have one on the page you can 'abuse' that JSLink to load any file you want (on that page) Note it is not better then ONE linked CEWP file, but it can do multiple links (actually for CSS it is better to do JSLink, as they load very early on, so you won't get HTML and then **later** CSS be applied

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the links for **JavaScript** and **CSS** files in the content editor web part as we are using in **HTML** pages.

Or we can write css and JavaScript directly mentioned by @Rishi Jagati in his [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202023/can-i-add-more-than-one-link-in-a-content-editor-web-part/202026#202026).

As shown below:

```
 <script src="http://srv1:902/trials/Assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://srv1:902/trials/Assets/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://srv1:902/trials/Assets/jquery.easytabs.min.js"></script>
 <link href="http://srv1:902/trials/Assets/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Reference:**

- http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Promoted-links-The-New-OTB-Tile-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create one file (html/txt).Use link tag for css and script tag for yous js file in newly created file and refer in Contnt editor webpart.

```
 <script src="http://XXXXXXXXXX.js"></script>
 <link href="http://XXXXXXXXXXX.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```